# Inputting data into an external app from Java

Tags: java, redirect, java-io

I use this standard code to capture and display the output from an application in a JTextArea. The error checking has been removed. Works fine.

```
Process proc = null;
ProcessBuilder builder=null;
builder = new ProcessBuilder("java","-jar", "test.jar");                        
proc = builder.start();
Thread outputGobbler = new Thread(new StreamGobbler(proc.getInputStream(),     outputTextServer1));
outputGobbler.start();
```

I now want the user to be able to enter a command into a JTextField and for this to be sent back to the app. I have read many variants using pipes, System.out and redirect but as far as I understand, none of these methods do this.The contents of the app can't be changed. How can this be done? (Can this be done?)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Think user command as a string:

```
String userCommand = "java -jar test.jar";
String[] s = userCommand.split(" ");
ProcessBuilder builder = builder = new ProcessBuilder(s);
```

but becareful about user extra spaces in writing commands :)

Comment: sorry but I didn't write the question very well. I was looking for help to write a second application in Java in which the user enters commands in a JTextField as input for the app test,jar. Test.jar is a command line app where a user can type in simple commands.

Comment: I think my answer is still applicable. Suppose test.jar have a command like 'help me'. In this case 'help me' is an input for your first app and should be entered in JTextField. So the value of userCommand in my answer will be "java -jar test.jar help me". Indeed 'java -jar test.jar' is constant part and JTextField value is dynamic part of userCommand. I hope I'm clearly explained.

Comment: Thanks for your help. There must be one more line of code. I have tried builder.redirectOutput(); and other variants. When I send the JTextField, nothing happens.

Comment: Imagine JTextField has a value like String jField = 'help me'; (definitely the value of jField is determined by user. It's user input) . First app also have a constant string like String userCommand = "java -jar test.jar";. Now result is userCommand = userCommand + " " + jField; Believe me or not, you don't need extra command :) [Hope my explain will help you]